# How to automate deploying VM in azure with specific settings

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-templates

I want to deploy a VM with Windows 10 image in azure and then after deployment need to add some inbound and outbound rules in the Networking. It's annoying to do everytime manually. What is the efficient way of automating this task?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this

You need to capture your vm as an [**`image template`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Fclassic%2Ftoc.json) and use it to deploy  other instances using the same. This also can be achieved with [`PowerShell`](https://www.jorgebernhardt.com/create-multiple-identical-vms-at-once-with-azure-powershell/)

Other way is to use Azure [`DevTest labs`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/azure-devtest-labs-create-multiple-identical-vms-at-once-from-portal/)